# Is there a Japanese phrase that gets translated into English as "Steel and rice" coalition?

Tags: translation

In a course I attended about Japan, there was the mention of a "Steel and rice" coalition. I don't understand the concept, so I can't define it.

When searching for the phrase, one match was for the following, in "Japan Transformed: Political Change and Economic Restructuring" by Frances McCall Rosenbluth and Michael F. Thies:

> The result was a "steel and rice" coalition backing the LDP, whereby
>   heavy industry provided money for campaigns and farmers turned out the
>   vote in large numbers.

The book compares it with an "iron and rye" coalition in nineteenth-century Germany. This makes me suspect that there is not a Japanese phrase that gets translated into English as "steel and rice" coalition, but instead English-speakers merely made a snowclone based on "iron and rye".

Is there a phrase that exists in Japanese that gets translated into English as "steel and rice" coalition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「[農工同盟]{のうこうどうめい}」 is the only term I could think of.

I am pretty sure that it should predate "steel and rice" in English, but I highly doubt that it predates "iron and rye" from German.

Comment: It's literally "Agricultural-Industrial Alliance" though; the phrase"steel and rice" probably is unrelated to 農工同盟.